# Getting error of unexpected output during activation

Tags: plugins

I have seen one plugin named `lordlinus business hours`

Here is the link for that

http://wordpress.org/plugins/lord-linus-business-hours/

When I am trying to install it, I am getting error :

```
The plugin generated 2 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.
```

How can I resolve this error, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get that error, your plugin should still work.

The problem seems to be in `lordlinus-business-hours.php`, you need to delete line 10 and line 11:

```
?>
<?php
```

That outputs a new line that could cause trouble :)